# Selenium から Chrome を使ってファイルをダウンロードする際、ファイル名を指定する方法が分からない

Tags: python, python3, selenium, chromedriver

Selenium から Google Chrome を自動操作し、CSVダウンロードボタンの要素をクリックしてダウンロードさせることまでできました。

ダウンロードする時に「名前を付けて保存」のダイアログが出てくるのですが、「保存する場所」「ファイル名」を指定する方法を教えてください。

以下のサイトを参考に試してみましたがエラーになりました。

[SeleniumのChrome driverのデフォルトダウンロードフォルダを設定する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hikoalpha/items/fa8330391823aea2fbca)

よろしくお願いします。

#### Pythonコード

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions("chromedriver.exe")
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Users\\*****\\Desktop"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
#Chrome diriverのパス
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-41dea91d03de>", line 4
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Users\\*****\\Desktop"}
                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows 7
Jupyter Notebook

Comment: ダイアログが出てくる時点でデフォルトな状態では無いような？例えば1年前の記事ですが。[Python + Selenium + Chrome でファイル保存まわり](https://qiita.com/memakura/items/f80d2e2c59514cfc14c9)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/229714

Answer (score 1):

ちなみに、それはまさに紹介記事の注意点に書いてある内容ではないですか？

> **注意点**
>   `download.default_directory`にパスを設定するときは階層の区切り文字を`\\`とするか、文字列の前にRAWの意味の`r`または`R`をつけて記述します。`ex( r"C:\Users\{username}\Downloads\test" )`
>
> このときドライブのルート階層の文字は区切り文字を1つ`ex( C:\ )`にしないとうまくいきません。chromedriverのパスはスラッシュ(`/`)区切りとし、webdriverをインスタンス化するときに`executable_path`と`chrome_options`を引数として渡します。

エラーコードの以下のメッセージは、パス先頭`C:\Users`の`\U`がUnicode16進数8桁のエスケープ表現の始まりだと判断したが、16進数8桁が続いていないのでエラーになった、と言っているのだと思います。

> ```
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
> ```

紹介記事の注意点のように文字列の前にRAWの意味の`r`または`R`を付けて以後の`\\`も2つではなく1つにするか、逆に`C:\Users`の`\`を2つにするかすれば良いのではないでしょうか？

---

それから本来の名前付けに関して、この記事では「名前を付けてダウンロードすることは出来ない」が、「ダウンロードしたファイルの名前を変えることは出来る」と書いてあるようです。
[Selenium give file name when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34548041/9014308)

> You cannot specify name of download file through selenium. However, you can download the file, find the latest file in the downloaded folder, and rename as you want.
>   Note: borrowed methods from google searches may have errors. but you get the idea.
>
> Seleniumを使用してダウンロードファイルの名前を指定することはできません。 ただし、ファイルをダウンロードし、ダウンロードしたフォルダーで最新のファイルを見つけて、必要に応じて名前を変更できます。
>   注：Google検索から借用したメソッドにはエラーが発生する場合があります。 しかし、あなたはアイデアを得る。
>
> ```
> import os
> import shutil
> filename = max([Initial_path + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(Initial_path)],key=os.path.getctime)
> shutil.move(filename,os.path.join(Initial_path,r"newfilename.ext"))
> ```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
↓で「r"C:\Users\****\Desktop"」としてみましたが
エラーがでました。
書き方は合っていますか？

’’’
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions("chromedriver.exe")
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : r"C:\Users\****\Desktop"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
#Chrome diriverのパス
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
’’’

エラー↓
’’’
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
’’’

Comment: コメント欄に書かずに質問の方に追記してください。